# Прилипание элемента к верху экрана при прокрутке

Tags: css3, css

При загрузке некоторый элемент находится не в самом верху экрана. При прокрутке, когда верхняя часть документа скрыта, положение элемента фиксируется. Пример - [поисковая строка Яндекса при просмотре результатов](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D1%8B+%D1%81%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7+%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82+%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&lr=2).

Задача фиксации объекта (прилипания к верху экрана) решается при помощи javascript/jquery...

Возможно ли сделать это на чистом CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Без js нельзя. [Fixed Floating Elements](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/). Смысл в изменении класса для элемента при скроллинге.

Answer (score 2):

Если этот элемент уже вверху экрана, то можно использовать правила:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

Comment: если бы всё было так просто, этот вопрос не задавали бы, мне тоже интересна подобная возможность без js

Comment: Нет, элемент не находится вверху экрана. Добавил уточнение в вопрос.

Comment: Тогда придется еще раз уточнить, в какой момент вы хотите прилепить элемент к потолку? И вообще нужно подробнее формулировать вопрос.

Comment: Тогда без JavaScript не обойтись.

Comment: @invincible, переформулировал вопрос настолько, насколько это возможно.

Answer (score 0):

В CSS есть относительно новое значение позиционирования - `position: sticky`. Но оно, насколько я знаю, на данный момент поддерживается только в Safari, в других браузерах реализовать это можно на данный момент только через JavaScript: используете `Scroll events` и меняете `position: relative` на `position: fixed`.

Comment: Альберт, пожалуйста, уберите из ответа рекламную ссылку